# I am struggeling to run my selenium-python scripts in a new tab of the chrome browser where my jupyter notebook runs

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-webdriver-python

I am struggling to run my selenium-python scripts in a new tab of the chrome browser where my jupyter notebook runs.

Imagine the following script:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By  
driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```

Does anyone know how can I run the above script in a new tab of already open chrome browser where my local host runs?